# How to change audio output type to headphones?

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio

I have headphones* that Windows (7 Professional) shows as "Speakers" (see screenshot) instead of "Headphones". Therefore (I assume) it does not offer the "Headphone virtualization" enhancement (see image 2).
Is there a way to "switch" the type of the device as seen by the OS to headphones?

* USB: Plantronics 628 USB and one "analog" connected to the headphones jack of the laptop (it has a headphones symbol drawn next to it; this is the "Speakers / HP" item on the screenshot). The "analog" headphones have no enhancements offered at all, just a tab named "Effects" with a single "Disable System Effects" option.

*Edit:*

I also tried with a USB sound card on the same system, but it behaves the same. (SPEEDLINK VIGO, see [see discussion here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/90c87d01-122c-4b0c-bdab-e9469f9c6031/how-to-change-audio-output-type-to-headphones?forum=winserversecurity) )

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you use the software that is available for this device? [Software for Plantronics® .Audio™ 478/628/648](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/audio-628#fndtn-undefined)

Comment: The only one compatible with my headset is the Plantronics Hub which only allows some high level settings like: setting the software log level, ringtones, assigning its button to accepting calls over Skype and similar. Nothing low driver) level.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest contacting Plantronics.